# MVC3 Route Using Parameter Name in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have these routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("ListPage", "{controller}/{action}/{pn}/{ps}", new { controller = "home", action = "index", pn = 1, ps = 10 });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Which allows me to have URLs like:

```
/foo/bar/1/10
```

to control lists of foos on a page (page 1, with 10 items a page). Hooray!

However, the following gives a 404:

```
/foo/bar/1
```

Using `Url.Action("bar", "foo", new { id = 1})` gives the URL

```
/foo/bar?id=1
```

Which then matches correctly to the action signature

```
public ActionResult Bar(int id) { //stuff }
```

My thinking is that the first route in the table would not match, as both `{pn}` and `{ps}` are required.

So it drops to the second route, which should then match the parameter as `{id}`.

Obviously my thinking is not correct!

Question is: why is the route not matching without the parameter name?

Answer (score 0):

Just try with interchanging `routes` postition

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("ListPage", "{controller}/{action}/{pn}/{ps}", new { controller = "home", action = "index", pn = 1, ps = 10 });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that match /foo/bar/1/10 with the first route? More specific first, surely?